# Materials blocking UV-C radiation

Tags: material-science

What type of materials can block UV-C type radiation? Such radiation is used in germicidal chambers. Do these materials actually block all of the radiation?

Comment: Although closed as engineering, it's also valid to close this as too broad since it is asking for a list of materials that block the radiation (instead of, say, what physical properties make a material suitable for blocking radiation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a transparent medium (such as glass) the light transparency depends on the wavelength. At low wavelengths the band gap of the glass become smaller than the photon energy and hence light is absorbed. This absorption is really high except for the wavelengths very close to band gap.

Usually the glasses are designed to transmit very low quantities (<1%) in the unwanted wavelength range.

There are several materials such as acrylic, Polystyrene that block the UV, whereas other additives such as $\mathrm{CeO_2 }$, $\mathrm{TiO_2}$ etc. are used to mixed with the glass to block the UV. You can see few such transmission curves here.

[image: Transmission Curves]

Ref: https://www.gsoptics.com/transmission-curves/

Your concern is justified.You should always check this and ask for the test certificate or perform some test. But if the glasses are properly made they will absorb UV. Also they will not saturate as the absorbed UV light is re-emitted in the form of visible/IR radiation (that is not harmful).